# Filter javascript array with subarray childern and return parent

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

Thanks in advance.
Iam having the below array and am trying to work out with array filter in javascript.

```
[{ID: 16,ItemName: "SomeData 1", children : []},
{ID: 19,ItemName: "SomeData 2",  children : [{ID: 51,ItemName: "SomeData 3"},{ID: 41,ItemName: "SomeData 4"},{ID: 16,ItemName: "SomeData 5"}]}
{ID: 14, ItemName: "SomeData 4", children : [{ID: 21,ItemName: "SomeData 9"}]}]
```

If I search for **SomeData 4** then using filter it should return me something like

```
[{ID: 19,ItemName: "SomeData 2",  children : [{ID: 41,ItemName: "**SomeData 4**"}]}
{ID: 14, ItemName: "**SomeData 4**", children : [{ID: 21,ItemName: "SomeData 9"}]}]
```

**Q1)**
That the if the search keywords matches with any object in child then it should return include its parent content.
Even if it matches with parent then it should return the parent and child.(I have done with this part)

```
const filteredContent = ItemsList.filter(item => {
   return item.ItemName.indexOf(value) !== -1;
});
```

Can anyone can suggest a best way to excute **Q1**

Answer (score 2):

You could take a recursive approach and check  the actual object contains the wanted value or if children contains a wanted value.

If `children` contains a result, build a new object with updated children property.

```js
const
    find = (r, o) => {
        if (o.ItemName === search) r.push(o);
        else {
            var children = (o.children || []).reduce(find, []);
            if (children.length) r.push(Object.assign({}, o, { children }));
        }
        return r;
    };

var data = [{ ID: 16, ItemName: "SomeData 1", children: [] }, { ID: 19, ItemName: "SomeData 2", children: [{ ID: 51, ItemName: "SomeData 3" }, { ID: 41, ItemName: "SomeData 4" }, { ID: 16, ItemName: "SomeData 5" }] }, { ID: 14, ItemName: "SomeData 4", children: [{ ID: 21, ItemName: "SomeData 9" }] }],
    search = 'SomeData 4',
    result = data.reduce(find, []);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

**Modified Solution for nchildren in a object and their children to n iterations.**
**Use the same function but recursively. The below function works.**

```
var data = [{
    ID: 16,ItemName: "SomeData 1",
    children: [],children: [{ID: 73,ItemName: "SomeData 3"}, 
                            {ID: 57,ItemName: "SomeData 4"}, 
                            {ID: 59,ItemName: "SomeData 5"}]
  },
  {
    ID: 19,ItemName: "SomeData 2",
    children: [{ID: 51,ItemName: "SomeData 3"}, 
               {ID: 41,ItemName: "SomeData 4"}, 
               {ID: 16,ItemName: "SomeData 5"}]
  },
  {
    ID: 14,ItemName: "SomeData 4",
    children: [{ID: 21,ItemName: "SomeData 9"}]
  }
]

const filteredContent = (ItemsList, value) => {
  return ItemsList.filter(item => {
    let hasValue = item.ItemName.indexOf(value) !== -1
    if (!hasValue) {
      for (let key in item) {
        if (key === 'children') {
          item.children = filteredContent(item.children, value);
          hasValue = item.children && item.children.length > 0;
        }
      }

    }
    return hasValue
  });
}

console.log(filteredContent(data, 'SomeData 4'));
```

Hope this is the solution you are expecting.

Comment: This function could also be used , if more children to the children object

Comment: @AnkitJayaprakash this is a better solution than mine. You can use this one.

Comment: @AnkitJayaprakash i have modified the solution to have nth children, and their children for n iterations.

Answer (score 0):

You can traverse your array recursionally:

```
const search = (arr, keyWord) => {
  arr.forEach(element => {
    if ((element.ItemName == keyWord && element.children)) {
        searchResult.push(element);
    }

    if ((element.children && element.children.some(s=> s.ItemName == keyWord))) {
        let newObj = {...element};
        newObj.children = newObj.children.filter(f => f.ItemName == keyWord);
        searchResult.push(newObj);
    }

    if ( Array.isArray(element.children) && element.children.length > 0) {
        search(element.children, keyWord);
    }
  });
}
```

An example:

```js
let arr = [
  { ID: 16, ItemName: "SomeData 1", children: [] },
  { ID: 19, ItemName: "SomeData 2", children: [{ ID: 51, ItemName: "SomeData 3" }, { ID: 41, ItemName: "SomeData 4" }, { ID: 16, ItemName: "SomeData 5" }] },
  { ID: 14, ItemName: "SomeData 4", children: [{ ID: 21, ItemName: "SomeData 9" }] }];

let searchResult = [];
let wordToFind = 'SomeData 4';

const search = (arr, keyWord) => {
  arr.forEach(element => {
    if ((element.ItemName == keyWord && element.children)) {
        searchResult.push(element);
    }

    if ((element.children && element.children.some(s=> s.ItemName == keyWord))) {
        let newObj = {...element};
        newObj.children = newObj.children.filter(f => f.ItemName == keyWord);
        searchResult.push(newObj);
    }

    if ( Array.isArray(element.children) && element.children.length > 0) {
        search(element.children, keyWord);
    }
  });
}

search(arr, 'SomeData 4');
console.log(searchResult);
```